# Edit bool property of multiple Models in Razor ASP MVC Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC project in the latest dotNet Core. The model has a bool property and I would like to make it editable in the list of models in the Index view.

For example, If i have a model like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public bool Enabled {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to create a list where the user can update the Enabled property only

```
@model IEnumerable<Model>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Enabled)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Enabled)
                </td>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After the user update all the checkboxes, I could use a button like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" asp-action="UpdateEnabled" />
```

Then a method in the controller should get the list and update the DB

```
public async Task UpdateEnabled([Bind("Id,Enabled")] List<Model> models)
{
    var allDbModels = context.Models.ToList();
    foreach (Model modelFromView in models)
    {
        var dbModel = allDbModels.First(dbm => dbm.Id == modelFromView.Id);
        dbModel.Enabled = modelFromView.Enabled;
    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I'm new with MVC and I don't know what is the best way of doing that. In the previous code the Controller never gets called.

How can I make that works? What is the best way of doing it in MVC?
Thanks!

Comment: Change your `@model` to `List<Model>`. Use a `for( int i = 0; i < this.Model.Count; i++ )` loop instead of a `foreach` loop.

Comment: My problem in the previous code is that the controller does not get called. I assume that the whole idea is wrong and it should be done differently in MVC

Comment: You want to use the `asp-action` on a `<form>` element that wraps all your form elements.

Comment: Thanks @poke ! Now it calls the controller, but i can't manage to get the parameters right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to change the data you are sending. Instead of sending a list of all `Model` objects which include the ID and whether they are enabled, just send the list of enabled IDs. You could do it like this:

```
@model UpdateEnabledViewModel

<form asp-action="UpdateEnabled" method="post">
  <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AvailableItems)
    {
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectedItems[]" value="@item.Id" /> @item.Id</label></li>
    }
  </ul>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `SelectedModel[]` name then allows you to retrieve an array of these values in the model that gets posted to your action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // example data to have the same ids between requests
    private static readonly Guid[] ids = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult UpdateEnabled()
    {
        // create view model, with the available items that can be selected
        var model = new UpdateEnabledViewModel
        {
            AvailableItems = ids.Select(id => new Model { Id = id }).ToArray(),
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateEnabled(UpdateEnabledViewModel model)
    {
         return Json(model.SelectedItems);
    }
}

public class UpdateEnabledViewModel
{
    public Guid[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public Model[] AvailableItems { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

This will then only transfer the selected ids, instead of all ids with a boolean whether they are selected. So you are saving traffic while making everything a bit easier. This will also allow you to include more properties in `Model`, e.g. for a `Label` that you then display next to the checkbox.

Comment: It still does not bind the properly. UpdateEnabledModel is null

Comment: @CarlosGarcia , also notice you are using `ID ` in `Model` , but use `Id` in your page .

Comment: Thanks @NanYu, I wrote a simple model to simplify my problem, In reality my model is different :)

Comment: I have tried with string[] instead of Guid[], with and without [], post and get,... nothing seems to be able to  bind to the controller - it is always null

Comment: @CarlosGarcia I’ve expanded my example to be fully working on its own. Hope this helps.